# angular2 access module on runtime

Tags: javascript, angular

In angular 1.x, you have the ability to access a module on runtime, and that way, to enable adding or changing things in the module from two diffrent files:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <script src="file1.js"></script>
  <script src="/api/extendAppFromDb"></script>
</body>
```

**file1.js:**

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
  .directive('someDirective', [...])
  .factory('someFactory', [...])
```

**/api/extendAppFromDb**

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .config([ '$provide', function($provide) {    
    $provide.decorator('someFactory', ['$delegate', function ($delegate) {
      ...
      return $delegate;
    }]);
  }]);
```

in my case, I am doing this to enable diffrent consumers of `myApp`, to add their custom code, without the need to recompile & deploy `myApp`.

is there any way to do such a thing in angular 2?

Comment: are you looking for something like [for-root](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#core-for-root)?

Comment: nope. I want the main module to be "unaware" of the second one, which is optinal.

Comment: Lazy loading ? (Not sure to understand what you're looking for)

Comment: Well, then I would need something like this: https://github.com/Quramy/angular2-load-children-loader/blob/master/README.md, which meens I would have to compile both modules together.